# UIButton Round Corner not working properly on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

this is by UI extension method

```
extension UIView {
func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radiusWidth: CGFloat,radiusHeight: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radiusWidth/2, height: radiusHeight/2))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}}
```

by this extension method i want to make my buttons with round corners with this code on viewdidload

```
 btnRideNow.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight], radiusWidth: btnRideNow.frame.width,radiusHeight: btnRideNow.frame.height )
 btnRideLater.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft], radiusWidth: btnRideLater.frame.width,radiusHeight: btnRideLater.frame.height )
```

but on iPhone 5 i am getting this result 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeFiE.png)

you can see left button wouldn't render properly but in iPhone 6 this work properly Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all a matter of timing.

If you call `roundCorners` *too soon*, e.g. in `viewDidLoad`, the button's `frame` and `bounds` may not yet have been finalized. But your `roundCorners` depends on the `bounds`, so if you add the mask and the button is *then* resized as a result of *layout*, you will naturally get the wrong result.

Comment: thanks i put code on viewDidAppear and its works as i want

Comment: Just be careful, though, because `viewDidAppear` can be called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you want round corners you can simple do:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius
```

and if you want a border you can do

```
view.layer.borderWidth
```

and color

```
view.layer.borderColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple subclass that works with IB. You should be able to easily adapt it to your needs:

```
@IBDesignable
public class Button: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable public var borderColor:UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you wish to simply code things, you were given most of the answer. For a complete circle:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.height / 2
```

You can use width though, if it's square. But like @Matt says (he's *very* good), be careful to do this **after** you have the frame/bounds properly set!

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @Sneak, I didn't mean to steal - and since Matt's answer was accepted that's all that matters. You didn't give a *full* example of what .cornerRadius needs to be. Peace! No harm meant, and I'm deleting my answer in a minute. I may be wrong, but I've always thought a Q/A site that wants MVCE for questions also meant for that as an answer. But sincerely, peace.

Comment: no  need to delete m8, you gave a good answer and I upvoted yours. let it be dont delete it :)